# update a UILabel when the cell in UITableView is selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

A really simple question here. I have a label on one view and a UITableView on the previous view. I have got a segue triggered when the user selects the row and I want the label to be updated with the text from that row. Here's one example, the code is pretty obvious.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *countrySelection;

switch (indexPath.section) {

    case kFirstSection:
        countrySelection = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"The country you have chosen is %@",
                            [self.MyCountries objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"doneResults" sender:self];
        self.countryResult.text = countrySelection;
break;
```

The label isn't updated and I just don't know what should be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the label you want to update is part of the controller's view to which you want to segue?

Comment: They both belong to one class and both are modal views, the label is just on the next view

Comment: Did you implement prepareForSegue:? If not, implement it and try to set the label inside that function. Also make sure that you label isn't nil.

Comment: prepareForSegue is there and unfortunately I can't figure out how to set the label inside this function :(

Comment: A segue always instantiates the object it's going to show. Even though both your views are modal, they must have a view controller, right? So just set you label as property in the view controller and then access it through the destinationViewController property of the segue.

Comment: Well this sounds like it's easy but I don't have enough experience to express it in code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of things really need to be set on the View Controller that owns them.  Use a public property to pass the value of the selected country to that view controller as outlined below:

First, create a property called something like:

```
@property(non atomic,strong) NSString *countryChosen;
```

in the destination View Controller, and make sure to `@synthesize` it

No reason to create another property for the IndexPath.  Just use

```
// Pass along the indexPath to the segue prepareForSegue method, since sender can be any object
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"doneResults" sender:indexPath];
```

in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Then in the `prepareForSegueMethod`:

```
MyDestinationViewController *mdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

mdvc.countryChosen = [self.MyCountries objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
```

On the `viewDidLoad` event of the Destination VC, just use:

```
self.countryResult.text = countryChosen;
```

*** EDIT ***
To deal with a datasource that has multiple sections, just use the same logic that you have in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

N`SDictionary *selRow = [[self.countriesIndexArray valueForKey:[[[self.countriesIndexArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:sindexPath.row];`

Change this to suit your needs, but basically you are implementing the same logic that you would to display a cell, except you are specifying the indexPath (both section and row) that you want.

Then something like the following to set that property on the destination VC:

```
self.countryResult.text = [selRow valueForKey@"Country"];
```

Comment: By the way, if I have different NSArrays like 'MyCountries', what should I do?

Comment: If they are being used as a TableView datasource, then you would handle them the same way.

Comment: They are just different sections in one table, having the same TableView datasource

Comment: Good answer ElJay. Technically indexPath isn't the sender, but it doesn't matter in this case. Also good point on having the actual owning VC setting it's field's text.

Comment: I still don't get how could we handle different sections of the same table that are set in different NSArrays?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you are asking SergiusGee.  Look in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method (for the TableView).  However you have that cell defined is how you would implement the code that you need in the prepareForSegue method.  I edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe I agree that the sender isn't the indexPath, but sender can be any object you need.

Comment: @ElJay so as far as I understnad we just create an NSDictionary containing all the arrays and then doing the same thing?

Comment: ElJay, When I use your code Xcode gives me a mistake saying: "No visible @interface of NSArray declares the selector allKeys"

Answer (score 0):

In your current view controller create a new property for the indexPath of the cell the user selected, like this:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *path;
```

@synthesize it and then when a user selects a row, set it by using

```
self.path = indexPath;
```

When you perform a segue, it will always call

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

So what you can do now when prepareForSegue: gets called, is the following:

```
/* if this is not the only segue you are performing you want to check on the identifier first to make sure this is the correct segue */
NSString *countrySelection = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithFormat:@"The country you have chosen is %@",
                        [self.MyCountries objectAtIndex: self.path.row]];

segue.destinationViewController.countryResult.text = countrySelection;

/* after creating the text, set the indexPath to nil again because you don't have to keep it around anymore */
self.path = nil;
```

For this to work the view controller you want to show after selecting the cell must have a property for the UILabel, on which you are trying to set the text.

Comment: Now Xcode gives me a mistake saying "property 'countryResult' not found on object of type 'id'" and I do have the property set @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countryResult;

Comment: It tells you that because you didn't cast the destinationViewController to your controller's class.  Add (YourControllerClass*) in front of segue.destinationViewController.country...

Comment: Thank you for devoting some of your time to my question, but ElJay's approach was better.